# How to wrap fscanf() using only fread() and vsscanf()

Tags: c, pointers, stream, scanf, fread

I'm porting some code on an embedded platform that uses a C-like API. The original code uses `fscanf()` to read and parse data from files. Unfortunately on my API I don't have a `fscanf()` equivalent, so prior to the actual porting I'm trying to obtain the same behavior of `fscanf()` using `fread()` and `vsscanf()` (which I do have). I also have the equivalent of `fseek()` and `ftell()`.

**EDIT**: please keep in mind that the access to the embedded filesystem is very limited (fread - fseek - ftell - fgetc - fgets), so I need a solution that works with strings in memory rather than accessing the file in some other way.

The code looks something like this:

```
int main()
{
  [...] /* variable declarations and definitions */
  do
    {
      read = wrapped_fscanf(pFile, "%d %s", &val, str);
    } while (read == 2);
  fclose(pFile);
  return 0;
}

int wrapped_fscanf(FILE *f, const char *template, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, template);
  char tmpstr[50];
  fread(tmpstr, sizeof(char), sizeof(tmpstr), f);
  int ret = vsscanf(tmpstr, template, args);
  long offset = /* ??? */
  fseek(f, offset, SEEK_CUR);
  va_end(args);
  return ret;
}
```

The problem is that `fscanf()` moves the pointer to the position in the file stream at the end of the match, whereas with `fread()` I'm reading a fixed amount of data (in this case 50 bytes) and I should find a way to move the pointer back to the end of the matched string.

Let's assume that the 50-char string I read from the file is the following:

> 12 ba**r** 13 foo 5678901234567890123456789012345678**9**

`fscanf()` would match the int `12` , the string `bar` and the pointer would point right after the "r" in "bar" so I can call it again and read `13 foo`

On the other hand `fread()` puts the pointer after the last char in the 50-element sequence, which is wrong: I still have to read `13 foo` but if I call `wrapped_fscanf()` again the pointer is in the 51st position.

I have to use `fseek()` to roll back to the end of the first match, but how do I do that? How do I calculate the value of `offset` ?

`vsscanf()` returns the number of matches, not the length of the string and I have no way of knowing how many whitespace charachters separate the elements of the match (**or do I?**)

I.e. I get the same outputs( {var,str,read} == {9,"xyz",2} ) with

```
9 xyz
```

and

```
9          xyz
```

Is there some trick that I'm not aware of or do I have to find another solution other than wrapping `fscanf()` with `fread()` `vsscanf()` `ftell()` and `fseek()`?

Thank you

Comment: With `fread` you can read chars 1 by 1 and do your stuff with data.

Comment: I thought about a 1-by-1 solution but I'm afraid it would be terribly slow. If only I could strlen() the matched string by vsscanf() ...

Comment: You can also use, if available, [strchr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) but obviously you have to parse your input somehow...

Comment: Are all calls to the former `fscanf()` made with the intent to read a _line_ of data?

Comment: Do _any_ of the `fscanf()` formats use `"%c"`, `"%["`, `"%n"`?  (Specifiers that do not consume leading spaces)

Comment: Are you sure `vfscanf` is not available?

Comment: @LPs vfscanf is not available. The only ways I can read a file are _fread _fgetc. Not even _fgets because at the moment is bugged.

Comment: @chux I'm not sure because I did not write the code I'm porting and it's quite complicated. But if I manage to write a 100% fscanf() compatible wrapper I don't have to worry about that

Comment: So I still saying: use `_fget` to read out data until you collect the requested number of elements and pass the retrieved string to `vsscanf`.

Comment: @LPs yes that should work 100% but I should call vsscanf() on every iteration of gets() and that's very inefficient. I'm now trying to follow the indications in the accepted answer. I didn't know about `%n` field descriptor and it's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: I meant every iteration of get**c** not get**s**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your `vsscanf()` implementation supports it, your substitute for `fscanf()` can append a `%n` field descriptor to the end of the provided format.  As long as there is no failure prior to `vsscanf()` reaching that field, it will store the number of characters consumed up to that point in the corresponding argument.  You could then use that result to reposition the stream appropriately.  That would require a bit of varargs wrangling and probably some macro assistance, but I think it could be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some intermediary buffering code, that will grab chunks of data (using fread), and scan your buffer for the pattern.  if the pattern is found, truncate the buffer, if the pattern is not found, append some more data.  this is effectively what fscanf will do.

Comment: Yes, but truncate how?

Comment: The 'truncation' depends on the buffering method.  The easiest way would be to memcpy from the end of the pattern to the beginning of the buffer.  If your buffer is a circular one (so you have a head & tail pointer), then this isn't necessary.